# Connecting two emulators to establish Socket connection between them

Tags: android, sockets, emulation

I want two connect two emulators and i wish to establish SOCKET connection between them.
Problem i am facing is I have to use two different ip address for client and socket.
Android emulator have static ip 10.0.2.15.
Is it possible to change the ip address?
If not then how can i establish Socket connection between 2 emulators.

The program i have is working fine with two devices,but how to do it for two emulators

Comment: Have you tried using different ports? You shouldn't need to use different IP addresses.

Comment: But in socket programming i have created a serversocket using device ip address and port number.then how can client on different device have different ip address.If server is listening  on port number 8080 client have to send request on 8080 port only.