# How to create Hotspot in Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I don't know how to create hotspot in AVD to connect two or more AVD through WIFI. I would like to run client and server program in AVD.

Comment: An AVD is not an actual device, and therefore it cannot offer a WiFi hotspot. If you want to connect two running emulator instances, [there are other ways of doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322533/connecting-two-emulators-to-establish-socket-connection-between-them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't need to create hotspot or anything* to test Client server program.
As both the **AVDs** are going to be created in a single computer they are suppose to be in the same network and testing should work fine.